# How can I remove the notification header in Android 4.3? (Big hour, date, clear all button, notification/quick setting switch)

Tags: notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean, notification-bar

As shown in below screenshot: is there a way to remove the notification header, or at least replace it with a transparent image, on Android 4.3?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you wanna do that?

Comment: This is why: http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/4079/ttza.png (it is my actual homescreen)

Comment: how did you make the notification shade fully transparent ? I guess your problem is there not with the buttons themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily- no. The notification shade is part of the systemUI APK which will need to be de-compiled and reverse engineered to do so. I know of no custom ROM or MOD at this time which will allow for this behaviour; although posting this request on the relevant sub-forum for your device on XDA-dev might turn up a lead.